# how to call web3.isAddress() via JSON-RPC?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc

`web3.isAddress` (and other `web3` methods such as `toWei`) works fine in the `geth` console, but when called from RPC (or IPC), it always returns

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"The method is_address does not exist/is not available"}}
```

`web3` is enabled by default, but still i explicitly used `--rpcapi web3`. This is confirmed by `socat`

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"admin":"1.0","debug":"1.0","eth":"1.0","miner":"1.0","net":"1.0","personal":"1.0","rpc":"1.0","txpool":"1.0","web3":"1.0"}}
```

i tried all possible combinations i can think of, such as `web3_is_address`. still no luck. any one can shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: how do you call it using rpc?

Comment: For example: `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_is_address","params":"0xafsdf","id":67}' http://localhost:8545`

Answer (score 1):

Acoording to the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#json-rpc-methods), the `isAddress` function is not exposed over json rpc.

**When using JS:** You can make the call locally by installing the web3 node package (`npm install web3`) when using JS.

**When not using JS:** You can also take the regex from the web3 [source](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/f8aa391351166316c81d7a70dcc95d695c8005db/lib/utils/utils.js#L403) and implement the function in your langauge of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I read that wiki before. Some methods such `personal.newAccount()` are not listed in that wiki, but I can still call them from JSON RPC. That's why I thought util methods like `isAddress()` and `toWei()` should be available via JSON RPC as well. And yes, I can copy the regex but that would be my last resort.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about the possibility to call the function over json rpc.